# Speed up python scrape sqllite3

Tags: python, sqlite, python-requests

I want to scrape NBA boxscores from the NBA.com json feed.  I want to know if there is anyway to speed up my current code.

```
def ParsePlayerBox(boxObj):
    statsDict = {}
    homeId, awayId = boxObj['resultSets'][1].values()[1][0][3], boxObj['resultSets'][1].values()[1][1][3]
    dateObj = parse(boxObj['resultSets'][1].values()[1][0][0].split('T')[0]).date()
    for x in  boxObj['resultSets'][4].values()[1:][0]:
         gameId, teamId, teamAbbr, teamCity, plyrId, plyrName, posStr, comment, mpStr, fgm, fga, fgPerc, fg3m, fg3a, pgPerc, ftm, fta, ftPerc, orb, drb, trb, ast, stl, blk, tov, pf, pts, plusMinus = x
         plyrGameId = gameId + '_' + str(plyrId)
         if mpStr != None: # PLAYER PLAYED IN GAME
            fg2m, fg2a =  fgm - fg3m, fga - fg3a
            minutes, seconds = [int(x) for x in mpStr.split(':')]
            mp = minutes +  seconds / 60 # CONVERT MP INTO DECIMAL
         else: # PLAYER DIDNT PLAY
            fg2m, fg2a = None, None
            mp = None
          if posStr == '':
             position = np.nan
          else: 
             position = posStr
          if teamId == homeId:
              isHome = True
              oppId = awayId
          elif teamId == awayId:
              isHome = False
              oppId = homeId
          statsDict[plyrGameId] = [gameId, dateObj, str(teamId), str(plyrId), plyrName, str(oppId), isHome, position, comment.strip(), mp, fgm, fga, fg2m, fg2a, fg3m, fg3a, ftm, fta,  orb, drb, trb, ast, stl, blk, tov, pf, pts, plusMinus]
    return statsDict



def ImportBoxScores(start, end):
    con = sqlite3.connect("nba.db")
    con.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NBAPLYRBOXTEST(PlyrGameId, GameId, DateObj, TeamId, PlyrId, PlyrName, OppId, IsHome, Position, Comment, MP, FGM, FGA, FG2M, FG2A, FG3M, FG3A, FTM, FTA, ORB, DRB, TRB, AST, STL, BLK, TOV, PF, PTS, PLUS_MINUS)")
    for gameId in range(start, end):
        urlBox = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscore?GameID=00' + str(gameId) + '&RangeType=0&StartPeriod=0&EndPeriod=0&StartRange=0&EndRange=0'
        rBox = requests.get(urlBox)
        boxObj = json.loads(rBox.content)
        playerBoxScore = ParsePlayerBox(boxObj)
        for k, v in playerBoxScore.iteritems():
            plyrGameId = k
            gameId, dateObj, teamId, plyrId, plyrName, oppId, isHome, position, comment, mp, fgm, fga, fg2m, fg2a, fg3m, fg3a, ftm, fta,  orb, drb, trb, ast, stl, blk, tov, pf, pts, plusMinus = v
            data = [(plyrGameId, gameId, dateObj, teamId, plyrId, plyrName, oppId, isHome, position, comment, mp, fgm, fga, fg2m, fg2a, fg3m, fg3a, ftm, fta,  orb, drb, trb, ast, stl, blk, tov, pf, pts, plusMinus)]
            stmt = "INSERT INTO  NBAPLYRBOXTEST VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"         
            con.executemany(stmt, data) 
            con.commit()     
    print gameId, datetime.datetime.now().time()
con.close()
```

It takes about 11 seconds to import all of the stats for the game.  I would also like to scrape the play by play data and that will be about 400 or so plays a game.  I don't know very much about SQL so I am hoping there is a better way to import the data.

Thank You

Comment: Have you already tried profiling and see where the bottle neck is? If it's the URL connection itself, then there may be little you can do Python wise.

Comment: Your bottleneck almost certainly lies with waiting for the NBA site to respond to HTTP requests. Such is the nature of network access. You could try accessing URLs in parallel, but you need to be *extremely careful* not to get yourself blocked for DOSsing the server (making too many requests at once could be construed as an attack).

Comment: The slowest database call is `commit()`. Use a single transaction for all the data.